# Dissecting hyphenated numbers in python, from the right side

Tags: python, string, trim

I am dealing with CASRN numbers in python, which can be 5 to 10 digits long, and always consists of three groups of numbers separated by two dashes.  The first group can be 2 to 7 digits, the second is always 2 digits, and the 3rd is always 1 digit.

So, 51-43-4 and 3242342-23-6 are both valid numbers.

I have hundreds of CAS numbers ranging between these two extremes, and I wish to add leading zeros to all numbers without maximum 7 digits in the first grouping.

What python tools will allow me to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zfill()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill)

```
lst=your_num.split("-")
lst= [lst[0].zfill(7)] + lst[1:]
fin_string="-".join(lst)
```

Comment: <facepalm> The idea on SO is to help people understand, not just "give dem deh codez".

Comment: @zxq9, to me, there is nothing magical in this code what a person with  304 reputation can't understand. However, it would be really helpful if you include which portion of this snippet are too hard/confusing to understand.

Comment: Yes, it's very understandable. Somehow I didnt come across a tool my searching.

Comment: The *code* is easy to understand, the absolute lack of discussion about how the OP would have *found for themself* this solution -- references to string operations in the documentation, explanation of the occasional overlap in Python between string and list operators, etc. -- is what I am talking about. Go read over meta SO occasionally -- [there are gobs of discussions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=give+me+teh+codez) about how to avoid engaging in pure snippet writing and why it is overall harmful and against the purpose of the site.